# Open source up-to-date autofill extensions for Chromium / Chrom* browsers?

Tags: web-browser, chrome, chromium

Unfortunately it appears that Autofill (https://www.tohodo.com/autofill/) for Chromium browsers is going to be moving away from a purely free model as it has been hitherto:
[image: new pricing]

I certainly do not condemn the author/developer for moving to this model.

I'm seeking alternative and up-to-date options to replace Autofill. Any suggestions would be appreciated as I prefer to keep this kind of functionality entirely free and open - and preferably open source if possible.

Answer (score 0):

KeepassXC along with [the browser integration](https://keepassxc.org/docs/KeePassXC_GettingStarted.html#_setup_browser_integration). It works well for passwords, but I don't really know about other things. It is also kind of complecated to use. Also, Google's own is pretty good if you are using Chrome.

Comment: Problem I have is that I need a very robust field filler that is not specific to passwords and usernames all of the time. Frequently, yes, but not all the time. Hmmm. I'd like something as flexible and robust as `Autofill`.